# Overriding onError in CameraDevice.statecallback gives error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, overriding

I'm trying to implement a camera interface in my Android app, but I've run into problems. When I try to implement CameraDevice.StateCallback I have to override the abstract methods (obviously...), but onError generates an error!

This is what I get in Android studio when overriding:

```
        @Override
    public void onError(@NonNull CameraDevice cameraDevice, @IntDef(value = {CameraDevice.StateCallback.ERROR_CAMERA_IN_USE, CameraDevice.StateCallback.ERROR_MAX_CAMERAS_IN_USE, CameraDevice.StateCallback.ERROR_CAMERA_DISABLED, CameraDevice.StateCallback.ERROR_CAMERA_DEVICE, CameraDevice.StateCallback.ERROR_CAMERA_SERVICE}) int i) {

    }
```

It's the @IntDef part that causes the error, but I don't know how @IntDef works so can someone tell me? Is it safe to simply remove it? If so, then why is it there in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is safe to remove.  Here is how my override of onError looks:

```
public void onError(CameraDevice camera, int error) {
 //do stuff
}
```

You can compare the int error value to the documentation at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraDevice.StateCallback.html#ERROR_CAMERA_DEVICE